# Inserting a count field for each row by a grouping variable

Tags: r

I have a data set with observations that are both grouped and ordered (by rank). I'd like to add a third variable that is a count of the number of observations for each grouping variable. I'm aware of ways to group and count variables but I can't find a way to re-insert these counts back into the original data set, which has more rows. I'd like to get the variable C in the example table below.

```
A B C
1 1 3 
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 1 4
2 2 4
2 3 4
2 4 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `ave`:

```
DF <- within(DF, {C <- ave(A, A, FUN=length)})
#   A B C
# 1 1 1 3
# 2 1 2 3
# 3 1 3 3
# 4 2 1 4
# 5 2 2 4
# 6 2 3 4
# 7 2 4 4
```

Comment: Why not `within(DF, {C <- ave(A, A, FUN=length)})`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using `data.table` that makes use of `.N`, which is described in the help file to "data.table" as *.N is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group.*

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(A = rep(c(1, 2), times = c(3, 4)), B = c(1:3, 1:4))
> DT
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 1 3
4: 2 1
5: 2 2
6: 2 3
7: 2 4
> DT[, C := .N, by = "A"]
> DT
   A B C
1: 1 1 3
2: 1 2 3
3: 1 3 3
4: 2 1 4
5: 2 2 4
6: 2 3 4
7: 2 4 4
```